# Karma Jasmine testing inject not working

Tags: unit-testing, angular, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine, inject

I am new to karma unit testing and I have encountered this problem to a simple Ionic Application.

This is my controller:

```
  angular.module('starter').controller('AccountCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.settings = {
      enableFriends: true
    };

    $scope.dummyFunction = function () {
      console.log("Just do nothing!");
    }
  });
```

This is my unit testing file:

```
describe('AccountCtrl', function () {
  var scope, createController;
  beforeEach(module('starter'));
  console.log("0");

  beforeEach(function () {
    console.log("1");
  })

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    console.log("2");
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('AccountCtrl', {
      '$scope': scope
    });
  }));

  it('should do stuff', function () {
    console.log("3");
    expect("Hello!").toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

At this point, when I run the test I get this:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LOG: 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LOG: '0'

LOG: '1'
LOG: '3'
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) AccountCtrl should do stuff FAILED
    forEach@/Users/eduard.lache/Documents/dummyProjects/unitTestingAPP/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13696:24
    loadModules@/Users/eduard.lache/Documents/dummyProjects/unitTestingAPP/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17883:12
    createInjector@/Users/eduard.lache/Documents/dummyProjects/unitTestingAPP/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17805:30
    workFn@/Users/eduard.lache/Documents/dummyProjects/unitTestingAPP/www/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2353:60
    /Users/eduard.lache/Documents/dummyProjects/unitTestingAPP/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17923:53
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.004 secs / 0.011 secs)
```

As you can see from the console.log messages, the inject function is not getting called and the problem is that I don't know why is that and why is this making my test fail as the test expects the string "Hello!" to be defined, which it is.

If I remove the beforeEach that contains the injection the test is successfull.

My goal is to make a test that verifies that $scope.dummyFunction() has been called and that $scope.settings is defined.
i.e.:

```
  it('should do stuff', function () {
    var ctrl = controller();
    ctrl.dummyFunction();
    expect(ctrl.dummyFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ctrl.settings).toBeDefined();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new testing Node and I just solved the same problem that you had. If it can you help, I solve this problem check all dependencies of app and put they in karma's configuration file. Then, I check that all dependencies ("dev" also) are installed and run karma, and this works! =D

I hope it helps someone.
=)